# Tensorflow Image Retraining Tutorial Bazel Error

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the Tensorflow image retraining tutorial located [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining).

When I try to run this command using bazel:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain --image_dir ~/flower_photos
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/j/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 108, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "/home/j/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/home/j/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *
File "/home/j/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 76, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
File "/home/j/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 28, in <module>
from autograd import core as ag_core
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autograd'

However, when I run it using the python command

```
python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py --image_dir ~/flower_photos
```

It runs correctly and does not generate this error.

I am running both of the above commands from the `~/tensorflow` directory (the top of the git repo)

Environment:

- Ubuntu 17.04
- Python 3.6.1
- Anaconda 4.4.0
- Bazel 0.5.4
- Tensorflow 1.3 (no GPU) (v1.3.0-rc2-20-g0787eee 1.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. The `autograd` dependency was not installed. This can be solved by running `pip install autograd`

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure TensorFlow before compiling, so it set up all the dependencies: `./configure`